# Can I ask about 'Vim Adventures' here?

Tags: support

I am trying to learn `vim` to make myself more efficient at programming. The way how I am learning is through the game 'vim adventures' (available [here](http://www.vim-adventures.com))

Since I am stuck on a level and need help, is it possible to ask here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A question about using vim *in a programming context* would be an appropriate SO question.  A question about using vim in a *non*-programming context (as is the case here) would not be appropriate on SO.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you have any suggestions to where I can ask it? Are there any SE sites or will it have to be somewhere  else?

Comment: @aPyDeveloper It *is* a game... asking on [gaming.se] would be appropriate.

Comment: @aPyDeveloper There is also a new [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](http://vi.stackexchange.com/) site that would probably be appropriate.